# How to deal with all deletes in Trie Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, trie

```
struct Trie {
        struct TrieNode {
            bool isEnd;
            array<TrieNode*, 26> child;
            TrieNode() : isEnd(false), child{} {}
            bool isEmpty() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                    if (this->child[i] != nullptr) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        TrieNode* root;
        Trie () {
            root = new TrieNode();
        }
        void insert (string &word) {
            TrieNode* curr = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                int idx = word[i] - 'a';
                if (curr->child[idx] == nullptr) {
                    curr->child[idx] = new TrieNode();
                }
                curr = curr->child[idx];
            }
            curr->isEnd = true;
        }
        bool isPre (string &word, int type) { // type 0 : isPresent, type 1: isPrefix
            TrieNode* curr = root;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                int idx = word[i] - 'a';
                if (curr->child[idx] == nullptr) {
                    return false;
                }
                curr = curr->child[idx];
            }
            return (type ? true : curr->isEnd);
        }
        TrieNode* erase (TrieNode* curr, string &word, int i) {
            if (curr == nullptr) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            if (i == word.length()) {
                curr->isEnd = false;
                if (curr->isEmpty()) {
                    delete curr;
                    curr = nullptr;
                }
                return curr;
            }
            int idx = word[i] - 'a';
            curr->child[idx] = erase(curr->child[idx], word, i + 1);
            if (curr->isEnd == false && curr->isEmpty()) {
                delete curr;
                curr = nullptr;
            }
            return curr;
        }
    };
```

I implemented the following code, but the issue is with the erase function. Specifically, say I insert two elements in the trie and then remove both. Then the isPre() function stops working. I guess when I call the erase to delete the entire trie, it deletes the original root, which is then accessed, and thus the issue.

But I am not sure how to resolve it. I tried adding a nullptr check at the start of the isPre() function but even then, I get the error.

Except for the case where I delete all the trie's nodes after inserting them, the trie is working fine (even when I have not inserted anything).

[Minimal Reproducible example](https://godbolt.org/z/7o5q93v31):

```
/* Trie Struct */
string str = "a";
Trie trie;
cout << trie.isPre(str, 0); // Working Fine
trie.insert(str);
cout << trie.isPre(str, 0); // Working Fine
trie.erase(trie.root, str, 0);
cout << trie.isPre(str, 0); // Creates the Error
```

Error:

```
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x611000000350 at pc 0x00000034e11e bp 0x7ffdd3c379e0 sp 0x7ffdd3c379d8
READ of size 8 at 0x611000000350 thread T0
```

Edit:
As, I had suspected the error was caused due to the root node being delete. So, I just added a condition that root shouldn't be deleted. It worked fine. Here is the [implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/vMYE6orGG). But, I am not sure if this is the way to go, I would be glad if anyone can suggest a better trie implementation

Comment: _"I tried adding a nullptr check"_ don't write code by guessing. Sit down and draw what your functions do, step by step, on a few short words. On the other hand, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::unique_ptr` and tries don't play nicely together. Tries require some kind of reference counting, implicitly or explicitly, and that doesn't quite fit with `std::unique_ptr`. Also, recursively destructing nodes is a recipe for stack overflow.

Comment: How did you debug it so far? Have you stepped through a debugger? When you write "Working Fine", does this mean it doesn't crash or that you checked that the internal linking is as it should be, pointers pointing where they should? In which line of `isPre` does it crash?

Comment: @Aziuth I haven't used a debugger yet. Working Fine is that the program doesn't crash.

Comment: what you posted is not a minimal reproducible example. A [mcve] I could copy/paste and compile, but yours is incomplete. When I try to compile, this happens: https://godbolt.org/z/o8avq4EKs (loads of compiler errors, but no crash)

Comment: please do not remove includes and using declarations from your code. It does not make the code easier to read or understand, but instead it will block others from compiling it. I can reproduce the sanitizer report and includes and using declarations was all i had to add https://godbolt.org/z/7o5q93v31

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry for that actually, I didn't know about this compiler. I actually compiled with Ideone (https://ideone.com/rLxXTo) but that didn't show any errors. But in Leetcode the error was there. So, I was not sure if I should include the ideone version.

Comment: any compiler needs the includes and your code needs the using declaration. Leetcode just hides certain stuff from you, but its still there

Comment: also leetcode enables the address sanitizer, which doesnt come as default with gcc, but you need `-fsanitize=address` to enable it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Will keep this in mind thanks.

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks for your advice. Drawing out the recursions helped quite a lot. Could you kindly check the edit to see if it's okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your code performs a `delete` on the root node, which should never happen. A quick fix is to only perform the `delete` when `i > 0`. Alternatively you could only perform a `delete` on a *child* (one level up in the recursion tree) -- that way the target will never be the root. This also means you don't need the return value to be a node pointer, and can instead use the return value to indicate success (if the word was found) or failure (nothing to delete):

```
    // Now curr is assumed to never be nullptr
    bool erase (TrieNode* curr, string &word, int i) {
        if (i == word.length()) {
            bool success = curr->isEnd;
            curr->isEnd = false;
            return success;
        }
        int idx = word[i] - 'a';
        TrieNode* child = curr->child[idx];
        bool success = child && erase(child, word, i + 1);
        if (success && !child->isEnd && child->isEmpty()) {
            delete child;
            curr->child[idx] = nullptr;
        }
        return success;
    }
```